# which keyvalue store has the best performance?

Tags: java, database

I think tow months ago. I found a google's open source project that can store key value pairs with high performance. But i forget the name. Could anybody tell me? or you can have some other suggestions for me? I have been using BerkerlyDB, but I found BerkerlyDb is not fast enough for my program. However, berkerylyDB is convenient to use as it appears as a java lib jar, which can be integraed with my program seamlessly. My program is also written in Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two strong competitors in the DHT (Distributed Hash Table) 'market':

- [Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/) (created by Facebook, in use by Digg and Twitter)
- [HBase](http://hbase.apache.org/)

[Here](http://www.slideshare.net/jericevans/an-introduction-to-cassandra) is a presentation about Cassandra. On slide 20 you'll see some speed benchmarks- 0.12 ms / write
(You can search around for the whole presentation, including Eric Evans talking)

Comment: You would need to access them over the network connection right? Would that be fast enough?

Comment: If you are using them locally, you don't need network connection. And Cassandra writes are extremely fast.

Comment: Thanks. I wonder how fast "extremely fast" actually is for a single machine / single process use case. Do you know any numbers or benchmark results? Are Cassandra and HBase optimized for this case, are they even ment for this use case? From what I read they are both specially made to be distributed.

Comment: @Thomas Mueller - yes, I saw some benchmarks in a presentation by Eric Evans. I will include it in the answer once I find it.

Answer (score 2):

Nobody mentions [leveldb](http://code.google.com/p/leveldb/) and yet this post is at the top when searching for "good key value store". Leveldb in my experience is simply awesome. It's so fast I couldn't believe it.
I've been trying quite a few databases for a task I was doing. I tried:

- windows azure table storage (expensive, value size max 1 Mb and each property size is max 64 Kb)
- redis (awesome if you have as much ram as you please)
- mongodb (awesome as long as there is enough ram, breaks after that point)
- sql server (expensive, needs maintenance, such as rebuilding indexes and eventually still not fast enough)
- sqlite (free, but not as simple to use as leveldb and not fast)
- leveldb. If you can model your job as to reading large consecutive chunks of data through an iterator then you'll get great speed. Writing is also pretty fast. Combine it with ssd disk and you'll love it.

Comment: Curious as to why you mention Azure Table Storage as expensive? 100 million transactions is about $10 (before discounts).  If you batch your queries it counts as one transaction.  You could in theory write everyone's social security number in the Unites States and read it back (using batching) for less than $1 dollar in transactions.  Storage costs would be about that as well.

Comment: @BartCzernicki I think of two reasons: 1) I really had lot's of transactions (partly increased by splitting data into less than 1 Mb chunks) and I didn't use batches (don't remember why). 2) Since I used table storage I also hosted on azure virtual machines (so that data travels through local intranet) and that if I remember correctly is 86$ per small instance per month. Anyway it's "expensive" relative to other options and maybe not that expensive in general, especially if optimised (like batches, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

[Bigtable](http://research.google.com/archive/bigtable.html)?

Answer (score 1):

Redis

http://code.google.com/p/redis/

Comment: I think project voldemort is although worth a look. Even though Redis answers the question :) http://project-voldemort.com/

Comment: You would need to access Redis over the network connection right? Would that be fast enough?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should describe what features you need. If it doesn't need to be distributed (does it?) then I would try using the [H2 Database](http://h2database.com). For those who think "it can't be fast because it's using SQL" please note that when using prepared statement, SQL parsing is only done once. Disclaimer: I'm the main author of H2.

Answer (score 1):

Many answer seem to automatically assume need for distribution; but that seems odd if question refers to BDB.

With that in mind, beyond Redis and H2 (which are both good), there is also [Tokyo Cabinet](http://www.1978th.net/tokyocabinet/) to consider, which seems to offer benefits over BDB. And one more newer possibility is [Krati](http://sna-projects.com/krati/).

Answer (score -1):

I think you saw [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) or Google collections.

Comment: Do google collections support persist data to disk? or just keep in memory?